# How to create parallel jobs in Bluemix Delivery Pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I wanted to create a Bluemix Delivery Pipeline which deploys built artifact to multiple bluemix regions on parallel, but I can't seem to figure out a way to define parallel stages and/or jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 stages, one for US deployment & another stage for UK deployment. In a stage,you can have Build & Deploy Jobs as shown in the image below. Run the stage parallel. Ensure that you remove Domain from manifest.yml

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done this as mentioned above.  Just have the second stage auto launch based on the completion of the first stage.  I also usually create multiple manifest.yml files (one per region - or deployment target), and then copy the appropriate manifest.yml file into the main manifest.yml as part of the script that does the deploy.  Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Move proper manifest file into place
cp manifest_testzone.yml manifest.yml
```